# java regex excluding string contain in brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have following code

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^get.*\\(");
Matcher m = p.matcher("getFieldAsDouble(String)");
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

It returns `getFieldAsDouble(`

How do i get only text name of method instead of `(` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex capture group

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^get.*)\\("); // The () creates a capture group
Matcher m = p.matcher("getFieldAsDouble(String)");
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1)); //Group 1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `.*` use `[^(]*`, which will get any number of characters that are not `(`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^get[^(]*");
```

Comment: This explains how to fix what matches, my answer explains how to get submatches using parentheses

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose your thing to be matched in parentheses, you're just getting the full match back

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(get.*)\\(");
```

Then you have to ask for the second item in the collection of matches, since the first one is the full match

```
m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround what you want to get with brackets, and then get that group:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(get.*)\\(");
Matcher m = p.matcher("getFieldAsDouble(String)");

if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // Group 0 is the whole match
}
```

Comment: @vidit beat you to it (me too).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it in one simple line:

```
String methodName = str.replaceAll("\\(.*", "");
```

---

Here's a test:

```
System.out.println("getFieldAsDouble(String)".replaceAll("\\(.*", ""));
```

Output:

```
getFieldAsDouble
```

Comment: doesn't do the same thing for different input

Comment: @JuanMendes yes it does. I've added executable code you can test for yourself. Incidentally, this directly answers the question. There is absolutely no need to capture groups or parse lines or do anything more complicated than this.